# Wordpress rewrite multisite blog url

Tags: multisite, url-rewriting, site-url

I have a plugin which creates sites progmatically.  What I need to do is ad a /s/ inbetween the domain and the site name in the URL.

So

`http://domain.com/site-name/`

becomes

`http://domain.com/s/site-name`

I have changed the sites url by adding `/s/` to the path when calling `wpmu_create_blog()` .

I now need to update the rewrite rules to cater for the added s.

`add_rewrite_rule('^/s/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?', 'top');`

What do I add to the second part of the rewrite rule (after `index.php?`, so that the site will load correctly?)

Comment: I don't think you'd be adding it to `index.php` (as it's a WordPress core-file). `.htaccess` is where that kind of thing gets done.

https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess#Multisite

Comment: I am not adding it index.php, I am adding it to the index.php part of the rewrite rule.  I have updated the question to be clearer.

Comment: have you tried this? `add_rewrite_rule('^/s/([0-9]+)/?', '/s/index.php?', 'top');` or this  `add_rewrite_rule('^/s/([0-9]+)/?', 's/index.php?', 'top');` ... `.htaccess` files can run in each directory, so there's that to consider too.